# Member function with const modifier.

Tags: c++, overloading, function-qualifier

I have a class with two member functions which are differ only by `const` modifier.

```
class CFoo
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
  static int a;
  void dosmth() const {
      a = 99;
  }
  void dosmth(){
      x++;
      y++;
  }
};

int CFoo::a = 100;

int main(){
    CFoo foo;
    cout << CFoo::a << endl;
    foo.dosmth();
    cout << CFoo::a << endl;
}
```

The following code prints `100, 100`. Why is non-const dosmth being called? How can I call `const` version explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is non-const dosmth being called?

That is by design. If you have a non-const object, the non-const overload is chosen over the `const` one.

> ow can I call const version explicitly?

You need a context where your object is `const`. For example,

```
void dofoo(const Foo& f) { f.dosmth(); }
int main()
{
  CFoo foo;
  dofoo(foo);
  cout << CFoo::a << endl;
```

or

```
int main()
{
  const CFoo foo1{};
  foo1.dosmth();
  CFoo foo2;
  const_cast<const CFoo&>(foo2).dosmth();
}
```

Comment: or const_cast<const CFoo&>(foo).dosmth();

Comment: `const CFoo foo1;` will fail to compile because the members `x` and `y` do not have initializers.

Comment: @JesseGood Good catch! Fixed, à la C++11.

Comment: You missed a ";" after foo2 declaration :-).

Answer (score 3):

The const version is only called when the object itself is const. This means you can call the const version with this code:

```
int main(){
    const CFoo foo;
    cout << CFoo::a << endl;
    foo.dosmth();
    cout << CFoo::a << endl;
}
```